# python dict get variable name

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dict defined

```
AMTVALUE1 = "string 1"
AMTVALUE2 = "string 2"

all_templates = {
    "amt": AMTVALUE1,
    "cmvb": AMTVALUE2,    
}
```

when i do `all_templates["amt"]` output is `string 1` as expected.

I would like to know if there is a way to access the actual variable name that is being used for the key value pair? So instead of outputting `string 1`, I would like to output the variable name that is used for the value.

the output would be `AMTVALUE1` or `AMTVALUE2`

Comment: No there isn't. Why do you need this? It smells suspiciously like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/174780)

Comment: There could possibly be a way to do that, but it's terrible practice to have your logic rely on the names of variables. This is a clear case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/858527).

Comment: Once you put the value into the dictionary, it has no connection to the original variable that was used.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I wanted to use the variable name to log it instead of the key

Comment: Save it into the dictionary explicitly.

Comment: Maybe something like `"amt": {"name": "AMTVALUE1", "value":  AMTVALUE1}`